# How can I fix the 'empty drag box' effect on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, drag-and-drop

I only have a small problem, which isn't really a problem, more of just an annoyance. When you drag a window around in Server 2008 R2, it just shows a outline, much like Windows 98. Here's a screenshot demonstrating what I'm talking about. I'm using the Desktop Experience feature, and Aero is turned on. Anyone know a way to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ensure it's turned on:

- Head to `Control Panel\System and Security\System`.
- Click the "Advanced System Settings" link in the left pane.
- Under the "Advanced" tab, in the "Performance" box, click `Settings`.
- In the list under the "Visual Effects" tab, ensure "Show window contents while dragging" is check-marked.

[image: Performance Options]